# How do I include php within php?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to include:

```
<?php the_field('200_200_1', 'option'); ?>
```

before the opening div tag in the line below...

```
$output .= '<div class="datebarcolor">'.$dates4.'</div>';
```

I am not sure how to insert the php tag in these circumstances. This is a php file, btw.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try `include 'your_file_path.php';` at the point you need it. But I do not advice it in your case. Try learning about **templating** - have a google on it.

Comment: Why do you need to insert a PHP tag when PHP interpreter is running?

Comment: @EdHeal I think _separation of concerns_ ?! Looks like it...

Comment: @MarkusHofmannn - I was assuming that the PHP tag was `<?php`? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `ACF` in wordpress you can use `get_field()` over `the_field()` in order to store the output in your `$output` variable:

```
$output .= get_field('200_200_1', 'option');
$output .= '<div class="databarcolor">' . $date4 . '</div>';
```

Comment: If this is the case, then this is a better way than doing it via output buffering. Edit: Apparently it is ;)

Comment: @Krister Sorry, one question. How would I add opening and closing div tags to `get_field();`?

Comment: @Desi - Something like `$output .= '<div>'.get_field('200_200_1', 'option').'</div>';` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the output of some other PHP code (for instance, if `the_field` does some `echo` calls) and you want to add that to the `$output` variable, use `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean`, like so:

```
ob_start();
the_field('200_200_1', 'option');
$output .= ob_get_clean(); //This appends everything to $output that was echoed since the call to ob_start
$output .= '<div class="datebarcolor">'.$dates4.'</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you either mean:

Include the file before executing this code:

```
include 'yourfile.php';

// ... some code ...
$output .= '<div class="datebarcolor">'.$dates4.'</div>';
```

or include the file and add it's output to `$output`:

```
// start output buffer
ob_start();
include 'yourfile.php';

// get buffer contents and clean the buffer
$output .= ob_get_clean();

$output .= '<div class="datebarcolor">'.$dates4.'</div>';
```